# Why SVG shadow is cut on the bottom side

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've made a little SVG icon that requires a shadow on the bottom. The thing that I couldn't understand is why its shadow is cut?

Thanks in advance!

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="default___3oPC0 barMiddleSVG___3x9T-" filter="" fill="url('#star_container_gradient_one')" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="0" width="43" height="36" viewBox="0 -1 43 38"><linearGradient id="star_container_gradient_one" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#c2c2b3"></stop>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#dedece"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<defs>
<style>.romb_top_border, .romb_bottom_border { fill: transparent; stroke: #e9ebd8; stroke-width: 1.5px; }</style>
<filter id="romb_container_shadow_bottom">
<feDropShadow dx="0" dy="2" stdDeviation=".5" flood-color="#4a444494"></feDropShadow>
</filter>
</defs>
<path filter="none" d="
            M 1 11
            L 21.4 1
            L 42.8 11
            L 42.8 26
            L 21.4 36
            L 1 26
            L 1 11
            Z
          "></path><path class="romb_top_border" filter="none" d="
            M 1 11
            L 21.4 1
            L 42.8 11
          "></path><path class="romb_bottom_border" filter="url(#romb_container_shadow_bottom)" d="
            M 42.8 26
            L 21.4 36
            L 1 26
"></path></svg>
```

Comment: stroke-width: 1.5px; color }

Comment: @MisterJojo Thanks for a spot, but it's not a solution here.

Comment: but it's not a solution here ... you paid me ?

Comment: viewBox isn't big enough and an 8 digit hex colour for the drop shadow is invalid.

Comment: I think the same of you. I just started reading your problem, and it was just an indication. Now will have to get by without me

Comment: @MisterJojo no problem cap, good luck!

Comment: @RobertLongson nope, the viewBox is enought. Did you play with it? There is a problem in something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things. Adjust your size of the svg to accommodate the size needed for the result of the filter on the svg element and it's `viewbox`, and increase the height of the filter to accommodate the boundary of the svg. Example below, hope it helps, cheers.

Oh, and PS, I assume the 8 digit hex color Mr. Longson pointed out is a remnant habit from say XAML Path habits wherein you can specify the alpha channel by appending a value to the first octet. AKA `<alpha opacity>RGB`?

```css
svg { border: rgba(255,0,0,.2) 3px solid}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="default___3oPC0 barMiddleSVG___3x9T-" filter="" fill="url('#star_container_gradient_one')" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="0" width="43" height="40" viewBox="0 0 43 38"><linearGradient id="star_container_gradient_one" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#c2c2b3"></stop>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#dedece"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<defs>
<style>.romb_top_border, .romb_bottom_border { fill: transparent; stroke: #e9ebd8; stroke-width: 1.5px; color }</style>
<filter id="romb_container_shadow_bottom" height="150%">
<feDropShadow dx="0" dy="2" stdDeviation=".5" flood-color="#4a444494"></feDropShadow>
</filter>
</defs>
<path filter="none" d="
            M 1 11
            L 21.4 1
            L 42.8 11
            L 42.8 26
            L 21.4 36
            L 1 26
            L 1 11
            Z
          "></path><path class="romb_top_border" filter="none" d="
            M 1 11
            L 21.4 1
            L 42.8 11
          "></path><path class="romb_bottom_border" filter="url(#romb_container_shadow_bottom)" d="
            M 42.8 26
            L 21.4 36
            L 1 26
"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's a very interesting problem... I've never faced with such thing (filter height + svg dimensions collision). +1 point to my skills pocket! Cheers! :)

Comment: No sweat, we've all been there, and honestly usually it's @RobertLongson serving me the humble pie on svg stuff. Either way personally I try to avoid svg filters in lieu of just good 'ol css. Could recreate that shape and effect with just css and be cross browser ready in no time if svg didn't work out. 